# How to change the Font of the text of dropDown control in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down control and when I close the drop down I catch the event in JavaScript. When I check a condition I want to change the bold style of the text in the display (for some values bold true and for others bold false).

example

```
 if (dropDownName == "OSComputerTreeFilterDropDownControl") {
            var OSLevel = "@SearchFilterGroupOP.Properties.Resources.Filter_OperatingSystem"
            var elementsCount = listBox.GetItemCount();
            if ((selectedItems.length == elementsCount) || (selectedItems.length == 0)) {
                dropDownControl.SetText(OSLevel + " : " + all);
            }
```

and I would like to have something like dropDownControl.Style.Font.Bold=true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JQuery to change the font weight. This can also be done in Javascript with a bit of editing.

**HTML:**

```
<select id="test">
    <option>Example 1</option>
    <option>Example 2</option>
    <option>Example 3</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$( "#test" ).change(function() {
$("#test").css("font-weight","800");
});
```

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuzpehhp/)

Comment: So is there a one line solution that can be inserted or not? And if  so what would it be?

Comment: For JQuery, it would be `$("#test").css("font-weight","800");`, replacing `#test` with the ID name

For Javascript, `document.getElementById("test").style.fontWeight = "800";`

Comment: dropDownControl.SetText(vulnerabilityLevel + " : " + all);
                    dropDownControl.style.fontWeight = "400";    The first one is the existing call and the second one is the one I added but it crashes with: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontWeight' of undefined

Comment: How are you getting the `dropDownControl` object? Through `document.getElementById`?

Comment: TreeViewFilters.UpdateText = function (listBox) {
        var selectedItems = listBox.GetSelectedItems();
        var dropDownName = listBox.GetMainElement().getAttribute("DropDownName");
        var dropDownControl = eval(dropDownName);

Comment: Isn't the function GetSelectedItems() ASP?

Comment: It might be... i'm new at JS. But the point is i get reference to a dropDown control in the Java script section of my cshtml file , with that reference i can update the text with the SetText method so the refernce is valid (i can see it done in the editor) . But i don't know how to access the font from this.

Comment: cshtml is asp, try `dropDownControl.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold`;

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: FontWeights is not defined , still

Comment: document.getElementsByName(dropDownName)[0].style.fontWeight="800";